# How to find many instances of a specific pattern in RegEx?

Tags: php, regex, recursive-regex

Currently (in PHP) I have the following regex pattern:

```
\[(.*) (.*)=(.*)\]
```

This matches [doSomething limitation=true]

The end result being that my code will interpret that string and replace it with whatever value is coded to return for it.

However, some of my code needs multiple variables sent through to the function, for example:

[doSomething limitation=true otherlimitation=false sendfile=1 title="hello there"]

How can I make the (.*)=(.*) in the regex repeatable so that it matches every variable sent through including the first (most important) name of function?

Comment: You should google for a ready-to-user BBCode-library instead.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it, but I don't want to overburden my code and make it any slower than I have to, this is why I prefer not to use bulky 3rd party written stuff.

Comment: Thats usually trying to replace the wheel with a box. In best case it will simply not work, in worst case you will introduce securit issues, that others already solved.

Comment: That may be true, but after inspecting the results of your Google suggestion, I have to mention that forcing anyone to install more than they need to to use my web application is going against the grain of why they'd want to use my web app above something like Wordpress or Drupal. Keeping the code to a minimum and very lightweight and easy to install/maintain makes for a brilliant, fast, extendable web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may work for you:

```
\[(.*) ((.*)=(.*))+\]
```

You may also want to replace your asterisks with plus-signs. Currently, your regex would match `[ =]` as a valid string.

```
\[(.+) ((.+)=(.+))+\]
```

Comment: It would appear that the + sign at the end makes it so that preg_replace() in PHP doesn't match anything. Any suggestions? In regex tester's it appears to work fine

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with the quirks of `preg_replace()`. Sorry.